# Which is more efficient?

Tags: java, performance

So I may have been reinventing the wheel and wrote a `Color` class.

I have setter methods to set the red, green, blue and alpha values of the color; But because the color is stored as an `int`, I must perform some math to do this correctly. Halfway in I started to wonder which of the following is more efficient:

```
public void setR(int r) {
    color = color - (color & 0xFF) + r;
}

public void setG(int g) {
    color = color - ((color >> 8) & 0xFF) + (g << 8);
}

public void setB(int b) {
    color = color - ((color >> 16) & 0xFF) + (b << 16);
}

public void setA(int a) {
    color = color - ((color >> 24) & 0xFF) + (a << 24);
}
```

... Where basically I am taking the old color value, subtracting the old red / green / blue component and adding the new one. My second strategy:

```
public void setR(int r) {
    color = (color & 0xffffff00) + r;
}

public void setG(int g) {
    color = (color & 0xffff00ff) + (g << 8);
}

public void setB(int b) {
    color = (color & 0xff00ffff) + (b << 16);
}

public void setA(int a) {
    color = (color & 0x00ffffff) + (a << 24);
}
```

... Where I am doing a bitwise OR operation on the color to "subtract" the red / green / blue / alpha component and then add the new one.
I am pretty sure that the second way is more efficient but please correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: Can you measure any difference?

Comment: I can't tell, but its pretty easy to test.

Comment: When dealing with very small amounts of efficiency I think its always better to go toward readability over efficiency.

Comment: My guess is that the second version is a tad more efficient because it performs fewer operations. However I highly doubt that you will ever notice a difference between the two.

Comment: It never makes sense to worry about such micro-optimizations unless they're a bottleneck.  Having said that, shift-and-mask is probably one cycle slower or else more resource intensive than shift alone on a reasonable number of processors, so the second form is probably a bit better and (to me) no harder to read than the first.

Comment: The reason i use a one hex value instead of a separate red,green, blue and alpha values is that it will be easier to read (and possibly faster) in combo with my game engine, as my game engine's graphics class stores pixel colors for <i> THE WHOLE SCREEN</i> in one big array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would opt for whatever is easier to read. I highly doubt tiny variations in the speed of execution of this class will affect anything measurable in your final application.

In your case, I would advise you store the RGBA values as separate fields within your class. Only combine them into an integer when required (e.g. in some getter method). That would strike me as the most readable, maintainable option.

Answer (score 0):

The JIT compiler of the JVM will take care of optimizations like this. So it really doesn't matter.

If you doubt, profile both variants.